# Cannot read an SQLite Database made in another language

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 databse I created in python. And by default it writes the database in Unicode.

Now I am trying to query the database in a Java Applet using SQLite JDBC. And I cannot find tables, rows etc because I think Java &/or JDBC queries in ANSI.

Does anyone know how I can query my SQLite3 DB with a unicode query in Java? Something like the following doesn't work (in Java trying to execute a Unicode SQL query):

If I access the database in python I can print out the tables no problem & make updates BUT if I try to do the same in Java, I get no results returned from my query. Is this an encoding problem or some thing else

This works import sqlite3

```
def blah(): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect( "a.db" )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    res = cur.execute( "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'" ).fetchal()
    print res
```

blah()

This returns no tables when it should return the same tables as above

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:a.db");
Statement stat  = conn.createStatement(); 
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
ResultSet tables = stat.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'");
String b = "";  

while (tables.next())  {   b+= "table= " + tables.getString("name");       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jim, that's very odd, it should work. Have you tried to open the DB from the console?
you can open it by running **sqlite3 a.db**

something that intrigues me, is that you're trying to open the db from a java applet. Have you given it the necessary permissions and signed it, so the apple can actually write to disk?

Comment: Another relevant question would be, "Can you create and populate a database using only Java and JDBC?"

Comment: I know its odd, I've gone & recreated a SQLite3 db using Java & JDBC & it works(can read it, I use the same SQL statements as in python BTW). And a python script can read the new database. It seems a SQLite3 db created in Python is not readable in Java JDBC

Comment: Jim, were you able to open the DB from the console, and validate that the data you've put there is actually there?

Comment: I can open the db in both the console & in python & determine all the tables are there & make queries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tired opening the `sqlite3 a.db` and typing `PRAGMA encoding;` ? It should say UTF8 by default.

I am able to create a UTF8 sqlite database on the command line and read the contents of that file using sqlite jdbc.

Are you sure you are connecting to the database that you created with python? IF the database does not exist then sqlite will create the database and it will not have any tables in it.  This is what is probably happening to you.

Are you running the java and python in the same directory?